# Remove CSS effect from individual elements

Tags: css

I would like make all text within div.main gray except for all content within the child div.exception.  div.exception should appear as if class main was never added to the parent div.

Is this possible?  If so, how?  Thanks!

```
<style type="text/css">
.main{color: gray;}
.hello{color: red;}
</style>
<div class="main">
 <div>
  <div class="exception"><p class="hello">Hello</p><a>Link</a></div>
 </div>
 <div><p>Howdy</p></div>
 <div><a>Link</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, due to the way the cascade works, this is not possible. You'll have to override the parent styles manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not possible.

You can easily override the style so that it appears not to have been colored gray, but then you have to know what the original color was:

```
.main .exception { color: black; }
```

If you would set the style on the inner elements directly intead of on the main element, and set the exception class on the same level, you could override it using `inheit`:

```
<style type="text/css">
.main div { color: gray; }
.main div.exception { color: inherit; }
.hello { color: red; }
</style>
<div class="main">
  <div class="exception">
    <div><p class="hello">Hello</p><a>Link</a></div>
  </div>
  <div><p>Howdy</p></div>
  <div><a>Link</a></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

for modern browser, just apply the rules to every div but .exception

```
.main div:not(.exception) p {
    /* style for very nested div not exception */
}
```

otherwise override the rules later (as suggested by @jacktheripper)

Comment: This wont work. `exception`'s parent div would still be getting those styles!

Answer (score 2):

This is simply done by:

```
.main .exception {
    your styling here (e.g. color: black)
}
```

See this [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/jackdent/wr87M/)

You cannot use `color: inherit` as this selects only the immediate parent, when you want to select two parents above. Therefore you have to override the colour 'manually'

@F. Calderan's answer is an alternative, but browser support is variable

Comment: I plan on first styling all elements.  Then, will use JS to add class main to the parent div to gray everything out, and add class exception to the child div to make normal. Will this work under that scenario? Thxs!

Comment: Yes it will, I can see no problem with that

Comment: So, should each element be styled twice?  One for normal use and the second with the .exception class?  http://jsfiddle.net/7zJkh/12/

Comment: Style all elements with in .main by using .main * {}

Comment: Then add the class 'exception' to those you do not want styled, or want to change the style of